# how to plot complicated function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-graphs

i know how to draw axis and everything else except the function here , please give me hint to plot this function

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of what you managed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4cm,y=5cm]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-.2,-.2) rectangle (1.6,1.2);
\draw[dashed,magenta] 
(0,0) .. controls +(0:.3) and +(181:1.75) .. (1.5,.97);
\draw[blue] (0,0) .. controls +(0:.25) and +(180:1.8) .. 
(1.5,.97);
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in {.1,.2,...,1.5} 
\draw (\i,0)--+(90:1mm);
\foreach \i in {0.3,0.6,0.9,1.2,1.5} 
\draw (\i,0) node[below]{$\i$}--+(90:2mm);

\foreach \j in {.1,.2,...,1.1} 
\draw (0,\j)--+(0:1mm);
\foreach \j in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1} 
\draw (0,\j) node[left]{$\j$}--+(0:2mm);

\draw (0,1.1)--(0,0)--(1.5,0);
\draw[red,dotted,thick] (0,1)--+(0:1.5);
\path (0,0) node[below]{$0$} node[left]{$0$};

\draw[blue] (.7,.7)--++(0:.4) node[right]{Debye}; 
\draw[magenta,dashed] 
(.7,.6)--++(0:.4) node[right]{Einstein};

\path 
(current bounding box.west) coordinate (W)
(current bounding box.south) coordinate (S); 
\path 
(W)++(90:.1) node[left=5mm,rotate=90]{$\dfrac{C_V}{3NK}$}
(S) node[below=-4mm]{$T/\theta$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i just needed to see how to plot these functions

Comment: btw how did u exactly draw this picture without using the function ?

Comment: I simply looked at you figure and use '\draw controls', controlling curve until getting similar to your figure

Comment: One should mention that this function is known, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model. In the case when the function is known I personally prefer to plot it and not to reconstruct it with curves, which is fine for unknown functions.

Answer (score 13):

You could declare a function and plot it. The relevant function is well known, see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        cV(\T,\TD,\a,\b) =
            (\a/(\T/\TD))^2 * exp(\b/(\T/\TD)) / (exp(\b/(\T/\TD))-1)^2;
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$T/T_\mathrm{D}$},
        ylabel={$c_V/(3Nk_\mathrm{B})$},
        legend style={at={(0.9,0.6)}},
        domain=0.001:1.5,
        samples=101,
        smooth,
    ]
        \addplot [black]    {cV(x,1,1,1)};
        \addplot [dashed]   {cV(x,{(pi/6)^(-1/3)},1,1)};
        \addplot [densely dotted,red,samples=2] {1};

        \legend{
            Debye,
            Einstein,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh i see so declaring function would solve everything huh ? , i appreciate a lot

Comment: @Quintis You do not have to declare it. But in this case it is worthwhile because you plot the same function twice with slightly different parameters.

Comment: Woow, thanks marmot! Is `\legend` a new command of the version `1.16`? Because I've never heard about it (I always use `\addlegendentry`, pros, cons?).

Comment: @manooooh `\legend` is slightly shorter. (Actually this was added by Stefan Pinnow, whom I thank for all edits except for the removal of `tikz` in `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}` since this does not only load `tikz` but also declares `tikz` to be a standalone environment, which is important when doing e.g. animations).

Comment: I use \draw plot[domain=.3:1.5,smooth,samples=500] (\x,{cV(\x,1,1,1)}); (with function in @marmot's code ) then it's okay. However, the error "Dimension is too large" appears when .3 is replaced by a smaller value. Is it true that pgfplots is more accurate than (pure) TikZ?

Comment: @BlackMild No, `pgfplots` uses the `fpu` library, which allows you to deal with large and small numbers. You can also load and use the `fpu` library with Ti*k*Z. However, `pgfplots` does this automatically and many things behind the scenes, so it is arguably more convenient to use.

Comment: Already I load fpu library, but still error "Dimension is too large" appears. Manual of pgfplots does not compare accuracy between TikZ and pgfplots. (I intend to use TikZ because it's not easy to remember so many keywords in pgfplots)

Comment: @BlackMild Of course, it is possible to make `pgfplots` more accurate than `tikz` by compiling with `lualatex`. In particular, trigonometric functions are not very accurate, regardless of whether or not you use `fpu`. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496922/121799) for a recent post, but there are many posts prior to this one I just do not feel like digging them out now.