# pgfmath / gnuplot: How to use gnuplot for complicated calculations?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, pgfmath

Is there a way to use gnuplot for complicated calculations?

For 
`\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{0.02}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x)^2))}` 
for example I get 'Dimensions to large'.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{0.02}
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x)^2))}
Calculating works not: % \y


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\newcommand\Curve[1]{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(#1) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(#1)^2))}
\begin{axis}[title=Graphing works:]
\addplot[blue,domain = {-0.07:0.07}] plot gnuplot[samples=500,id=curve]{\Curve{x}} node[anchor=east]{gnuplot: good};

\addplot[red,domain = {-0.07:0.07}, trig format plots=rad]{\Curve{x}} node[pos=0.5,anchor=north]{pgfplots: bad};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

gnuplot is more for plotting but you could use expl3's floating point instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\x}{0.02}
\edef\y{\fpeval{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x)^2))}}
\typeout{y=\y}
\edef\y{\fpeval{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x deg) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x deg)^2))}}
\typeout{y=\y}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
y=1.270132770126
y=0.000386870374
```

(Note PGF uses degrees by default in trig functions)

Comment: Wouldn't we need `\fpeval{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x deg) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x deg)^2))}` to have the arguments of circular functions interpreted the same way as with `pgfmath`? (I get: `0.000386870374`)

Comment: @frougon oh you want mathematically correct results not just an error free tex run? So converntional:-)  Yes thanks, I'll fix

Comment: Oh, no, rest assured: not me—but maybe cis? :-)

Comment: @frougon better?

Comment: You now have the same result I got: so we are either both right or both wrong, that's all I can say. :-P (well, you gave two results, kind of cheating!)

Comment: @frougon but both results are equal to y, so it's OK.

Comment: That's a *point of view.* :-)

Comment: Actually, the “reference plot” made with gnuplot interpreted `\x` as radians, AFAICT; so, that's probably what the OP wanted, after all. (== I could have shut my mouth :-X)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   Not bad. Of course there are other ways. Me had the question sometimes irritated, if you can possibly do it with gnuplot and its instruments...

Answer (score 4):

If I do things as the manuals suggest me to do, then there is no problem. In particular, you may want to

1. switch on `fpu` to use it. Just loading `pgfplots` doesn't switch it on. In fact, you need to switch it off again before you start a `tikzpicture`.
2. Use `lualatex -shell-escape` for the compilation.

Then the results are fully consistent.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{0.02}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 -
pow(sin(\x),2)))}
Calculating works:  \y
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}


\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(\x) +
sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(\x)^2));}]
\newcommand\Curve[1]{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(#1) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(#1)^2))}

\begin{axis}[title=Graphing works:]
\addplot[blue,domain = {-0.07:0.07}] plot
gnuplot[samples=500,id=curve]{\Curve{x}} node[anchor=east]{gnuplot: good};

\addplot[red,dashed,domain = {-0.07:0.07}, trig format plots=rad]{f(x)}
node[pos=0.5,anchor=north]{pgfplots: good};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not the result for `\y` is what you want or you need to add `\pgfkeys{/pgf/trig format=rad}` or something I don't know.

Comment: Seems to be good with fpu. But the value should be `f(x)=1.27013 for x=0.02` or `f(x)=0.000386 for x=0.02°` 

I thought fpu does not always work either. 
gnuplot creates an auxiliary file gnuplot01.curve.table You would have to somehow make him do that for the calculated value; and then read the table value.

Comment: @cis `fpu` does "work" but you are right in that it is not very accurate for trigonometric functions and small values. And yes, gnuplot generates a table which gets read. Similarly, when you use lualatex, the computations are not done by TeX, so they are more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

R have not problems with these calculations nor plotting the result with enough points:

[image: mwe0]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis', fig.width=4,fig.height=4>>=
x = seq(-0.07,0.07,0.0001)
y=2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(x)^2)) 
plot(x,y,type="l",lwd=3,col="blue")
@
\end{document}
```

OK, is the same parabola but not the same graph. Now with tikz look & feel:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis',dev="tikz",fig.width=4,fig.height=4>>=
x = seq(-0.07,0.07,0.0001)
y=2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(x) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(x)^2)) 
plot(x*100,y,type="l",lwd=3,col="blue", 
xlab="$x \\times10^{-2}$", ylab="$y$", xlim=c(-8.5,8.5),  
xaxp  = c(-10,10,10), tck=0.02)
axis(side = 4, tck=0.02, labels = NA)
axis(side = 3, tck=0.02, at=seq(-8,8,2), labels = NA)
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method that uses only lua, lualatex and tikz. The only reason I'm using tkz-elements and tkz-base is so that I can plot the axes and simplify the code. It's easy to avoid these packages.

`\tkzUseLua{fun(0.05)}`  is used to obtain function values in the text. We get `fun(0.05 = 7.9420153095815`

Currently, TikZ knows how to call `gnuplot`. It would be interesting to be able to call `Lua` alongside gnuplot.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-elements}
\begin{document}


\begin{tkzelements}
  function fun (x)
  return 2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - math.cos(x) + math.sqrt(1.40576^2 - math.sin(x)^2))
  end

  function f(t0, t1, n)
    local dt = (t1-t0)/n 
    local t = t0
    local out=assert(io.open("tmp.table","w"))
    local x,y
    while (t <= t1) do
      x = t
      y = fun(x)
      out:write(x, " ", y, " i\string\n") 
      t = t + dt
    end
    out:close()
   end
\end{tkzelements}


\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.05,xmax=.05,ymin=0,ymax=10,xstep=.01]
\tkzAxeX \tkzAxeY
\directlua{f(-0.05,0.05,100)}
   \begin{scope}[xscale=100]
     \draw[domain=-0.05:0.05,thick,blue] plot[smooth] file {tmp.table};
  \node [draw=black,circle,fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (0.02,\tkzUseLua{fun(0.02)}) {};
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

#### Short:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newsavebox{\mycalc}
% See too: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node53.html  
\begin{document}


\newcommand\Function[3][fixed,precision=6]{%%%%%%%%%
\sbox{\mycalc}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[blue,domain = {#3:#3+0.1}] plot gnuplot[id=mycalc]{#2};
%\addplot[blue,domain = {pi:2*pi}] plot gnuplot[id=mycalc]{5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%%
%\usebox{\mycalc}
%
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{\jobname.mycalc.table}\tempdata% 
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\tempdata}
%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\tempdata
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathprintnumber[#1]{\y}%
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\section{Easy}
$\sin(\frac\pi6) = \Function{sin(x)}{pi/6}$

\section{Difficult}
\newcommand\Curve[1]{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(#1) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(#1)^2))
}
\newcommand\curve[1]{2\cdot 11000\cdot \left(1 - 1.40576 - \cos(#1) + \sqrt{1.40576^2 - \sin(#1)^2}\right)}

Let $f(x) =\curve{x}$.
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{0.05}

$f(\x) = \Function{\Curve{x}}{\x}$
\end{document}
```

#### Long:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcommand\Curve[1]{2*11000*(1 - 1.40576 - cos(#1) + sqrt(1.40576^2 - sin(#1)^2))
}
\newcommand\curve[1]{2\cdot 11000\cdot \left(1 - 1.40576 - \cos(#1) + \sqrt{1.40576^2 - \sin(#1)^2}\right)}

\begin{document}
Let $f(x) =\curve{x}$.

\pgfmathsetmacro\x{0.05}
We need $f(\x)$

\newsavebox{\mycalc}
\sbox{\mycalc}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[blue,domain = {\x:\x+0.1}] plot gnuplot[id=mycalc]{\Curve{x}};
%\addplot[blue,domain = {pi:2*pi}] plot gnuplot[id=mycalc]{5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Show graph - for Info}
\usebox{\mycalc}


\section{Show gnuplot-generated table - for Info}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{\jobname.mycalc.table}\tempdata 
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\tempdata}

\section{Read out value}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\tempdata
%\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci}
%\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{\pgfplotsretval}

$f(\x) = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=6]{\y}$

$f(\x) = \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,precision=6]{\y}$

\end{document}
```